# Safari CSS relative parent & relative child with pseudo selector does not match other browsers output

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, cross-browser

I am not looking for an answer to fix the code, moreso an answer or explanation as to why.

Safari will render children elements with a relative parent in a completely different place than other browsers show. If I change the child to be absolute, it will have some consistency.

Edit: After looking at iPhone 8+ Safari & Chrome apps, it shows broke on both. So maybe this is a issue at the OS level.

#### Figure 1: In-consistent code (we are primarily focused on the caret with red background)

https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/eYVYyjK

```css
.c-anchor-explore--toggle {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.c-anchor-explore--caret {
    position: relative;
    right: -70px;
}
```

Safari 14 Output
[image: Safari 14 Output]

Chrome Output
[image: Chrome Output]

#### Figure 2: Consistent code (same caret with red background)

https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/xxYxpBe

I also moved the element closer and made it visually centered; however, that had no affect on the ultimate issue.

```css
.c-anchor-explore--toggle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 7px 0px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* remove border around safari */
  margin-right: 40px; /* match the right: -40px; to make sure it looks centered */
}

.c-anchor-explore--caret {
  position: absolute; /* cannot be relative as Safari will not render correctly */
  right: -40px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

[image: Safari 14 Output (fixed)]

Comment: Chrome on iOS [uses Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#cite_ref-App_Store_Review_Guidelines_45-0) under the hood.

Comment: Yep it sure does. Still have no idea why  I had to rewrite my code differently to get Safari to match other browsers, when really they are primarily forked code-basis of each other. I'm starting to think there is really no explanation as to why Safari does what it does and thats just how I will have to live lol.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`. Webkit is made to work for HTML5 on iOS.

```
.c-anchor-explore--toggle {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.c-anchor-explore--caret {
    position: relative;
    right: -70px;
    top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but my question is more specifically looking to understand why Safari is doing this. It is the only browser that produces this unusual result when using positioning. When this issue came up I had already created a workaround and solved the problem, but still was left questioning why the original way I have shown doesn't work. So if you have an answer to that let me know!

Comment: So from the perspective of a front-end web developer, browser prefixes are used to add new CSS features onto a site while having comfort knowing that the browsers will support those styles

Comment: Can you back that up with sources please Pinal